# Filtering list based on select value and css class on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a list where I need to filter the list based on a value selected in my dropdown list. All the classes and select option values are dynamic. But always the same. Like this:

```
<select id="picker" onchange="changeList()">
    <option value="0">Pick a side</option>
    <option value="The-good">The good</option>
    <option value="The-bad">The bad</option>
    <option value="The-ugly">The ugly</option>
</select>

<div class="The-good">
    <span>Superman</span>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery to do this. So far my JS looks like this:

```
function changeList() {
    var selectedGroup = $("#picker").val();
    if ($("div").hasClass(selectedGroup)) {
        $("div").show();
    }
    else {
        $("div").hide();
    }
}
```

But that's not working. Is there a way to pick the class from the div and put it in a var and then compare the two values in my if statement?

Comment: You said its not working but you never said "how" it fails?  You might also want to create a jsFiddle to allow potential responders try a test.

Comment: I tried: your code works. You didn't forget to add JQuery ?

Comment: [This fiddle is](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/3vktrn95/) how I see your code, even though your original code works.

Comment: The original code would either show ALL divs or hide ALL divs.

Comment: @Kolban which is OK with provided HTML. As usually, I'm not ready to guess how full related HTML really looks like.

Comment: @user1799619 it would be much better, if you had provided this HTML from the beginning. [Corrected version of my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/3vktrn95/3/), partially based on ADi's idea.

Comment: The idea is that when you pick a value the list only shows the div's with the matching css class. I can't seem to get it to work and yes I have jQuery added :)

Comment: @Regent Yeah you are right. Thank your for the time and effort. Your fiddle did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

If the `Value` is the `class` , then you can simply do this:

```
function changeList() {
                var selectedGroup = $("#picker").val();
                $('.' + selectedGroup).toggle();  
            }
```

Comment: @Regent : Yes. I Forgot about that. My Bad!! I personally will use the ids here and keep the class so that it will be pretty easy

Comment: Well, in this situation you can change code to `$('div').hide(); $('.' + selectedGroup).show();` to save the idea of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following along in your original design, the following code fragment will work:

```
function changeList() {
    var selectedGroup = $("#picker").val();
    $("div").each(function(i, item) {
         if ($(item).hasClass(selectedGroup)) {
             $(item).show();
         } else {
             $(item).hide();
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: `$('div').hide(); $('.' + selectedGroup).show();` is much shorter than `.each()` :)

Comment: Yup ... and ternary operators are more compact than if then elses ... but the thought here was to follow through on the original posters thinking in the initial design as opposed to a completely new (and better) algorithm.

Comment: I just hope that at least small part of questioners will learn how to right shorter, better and usually faster working code with jQuery. And to help them in this, we can provide "better" version of their code, can't we?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function changeList() {
        $('.children').hide();
        $('.' + ($('#picker').val())).show();
    }


<select id="picker" onchange="changeList()">
    <option value="0">Pick a side</option>
    <option value="The-good">The good</option>
    <option value="The-bad">The bad</option>
    <option value="The-ugly">The ugly</option>
</select>

<div class="children The-good" style="display:none">
    <hr />
    <span>Superman</span>
</div>

<div class="children The-bad" style="display:none">
    <hr />
    <span>Badman</span>
</div>

<div class="children The-ugly" style="display:none">
    <hr />
    <span>Uglyman</span>
</div>
```